# Карамели ночных витрин

Tags: лексика, семантика

Это фраза из песни Наташи Королевой " Серые глаза". Карамели ночных витрин отражают свет суетливых машин.

Вопрос: Что здесь имеется в виду - конфеты? Если да, то как конфеты могут отражать свет машин?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует понятие **"карамельный цвет"**, в котором смешаны блонд, бежевый и золотистый. Например, может обсуждаться использование карамельного цвета в интерьере.

**Карамели витрин** ― это освещенные изнутри витрины золотистого цвета, как и всякое стекло, они могут отражать свет, исходящий от машинных фар.

**Образ, конечно, смутный**, но, возможно, он кажется автору текста эффектной и новой метафорой.

Comment: Интересно! Возможно, вы правы. Подождем другие мнения.

Comment: Sibylla, вот что мне ответили в Ютубе: "Витрины такого же цвета, имеют прозрачность и отражают объекты. Вот и всё, никакого потаённого смысла".

Answer (score 3):

**Удивительный физико - лирический** вопрос! Попытаюсь ответить покороче.

**Преломле́ние (рефра́кция**) — изменение направления луча (волны), возникающее на границе двух сред, через которые этот луч проходит...
...термин «рефракция» чаще употребляется для описания излучения в средах, показатель преломления в которых от точки к точке меняется плавно.., (т.е. в больших витринных стеклах, подсвеченных изнутри ).

**Диспе́рсия све́та (разложение света)** — это совокупность явлений, обусловленных зависимостью абсолютного показателя преломления вещества от частоты (или длины волны)...

**Красный закат** — один из результатов разложения света в атмосфере Земли.
 **Радуга,** чьи цвета обусловлены дисперсией, — один из ключевых образов культуры и искусства.
 Благодаря дисперсии света, можно наблюдать **цветную «игру света» на гранях**  **бриллианта**.

**В той или иной степени радужные эффекты** обнаруживаются достаточно часто при прохождении света через почти любые прозрачные предметы.  **В искусстве**     **они могут специально усиливаться и/или подчеркиваться.**

**Рефракция** ( свет от фар встречается со стеклом: часть его отражается от поверхности под разными углами, другая часть проникает внутрь ), **дисперсия** и  **внутреннее отражение и преломление** света ( от предметов за стеклами витрин )  **накладываются** друг на друга.
 На стекле витрины может появиться  **любая** цветовая гамма ( **от красного до**  **фиолетового** ), но не сплошная, а  **пятнами, брызгами**.

Кому-то  **повезло**: он увидел особенные блики цвета карамели!

Comment: А по-моему всё проще. Карамель, карамелька - конфетка, она может быть хоть синей.

Comment: @Morkovkin  Совершенно верно:  "цвета карамели" - от красного до фиолетового.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что карамели - это разноцветные огонёчки (как и конфетки с таким названием), но тогда вся фраза кажется странной. "Карамели ночных витрин отражают свет суетливых машин". Эти "карамели" - скорее всего, результат общей световой игры на стеклянных витринах ночного города,  и  свет отражает именно стекло, тогда "карамели витрин" - это сами витрины.  То  есть это метонимия (перенос имени с предмета на его часть)? Довольно сложный образ: "золото витрин - сами витрины" - это понятно, а "карамели (цветные огоньки) витрин - сами витрины" -  такой перенос воспринимается с трудом.

Comment: Вот и я не могу понять, что имеется в виду.

Comment: Я тоже люблю физику, но по-моему, в этом ответе неоправданно много физики.

Comment: @М_Г "Изничтожила" лишнюю физику. ТАК лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, сомнительно, что слова самой Королевой написаны. Во-вторых, искать смысла в песенном тексте - занятие не благодарное.

Но если все-таки искать, то очень сомнительно, что здесь прямое сравнение витрин с карамелью (жженым сахаром). Скорее всего это именно те отражаемые огонечки - карамели или карамельки. Конфетки-огонечки, маленькие, прозрачные, свет отражают (особенно, если пососать сначала), разноцветные, совсем не обязательно желто-карамельные. Такое сравнение было бы весьма интересно.

Но автор просто "в размер не попал", вольно или невольно перенес эпитет на витрину. Вне контекста понять, конечно, невозможно, с чего это витрины стали карамелями.

Comment: Ну, слова написаны Игорем Николаевым. Хотя контекст вам вряд ли что даст в данном случае. Впрочем, еще маленький отрывок.

Comment: Карамели ночных витрин отражают свет суетливых машин. Знаю я, что в одной из них едешь ты ко мне в нашу ночь на двоих. Огонек такси  рядом с домом, подмигнет как старый знакомый, и как прежде я открою дверь.